# Absolutely continuous functions. Prove a limit.

Tags: real-analysis

I need help to prove this.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ be an absolutely continuous function in any interval of the form $\left. [ -k,k \right ]$. If $f^{\prime}$ is in $L(\mathbb{R})$ and $\left\{{x_n}\right\}$ is a sequence that converges to infinity. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{\infty}}{\displaystyle \left |{f(1+x_n)-f(x_n)}\right |}=0$

Thanks.

Comment: If $f$ is absolutely continuous $[a,b]$, then f has a derivative $f′$ almost everywhere, the derivative is Lebesgue integrable, and $f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(t) \, dt$.

Comment: What is the role in your hint of the form $\left. [ -k,k \right ]$ of the intervals?